# HTML5 video autoplay doesn't work on phones and tablets

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, html5-video

HTML5 video autoplay doesn't work on phones and tablets.

I checked on the phone with Android 4.2.2 in Chrome 60 and iPad. Also, I checked on the phones with Android 4.2.2 and 7.0.
I tried to use such scripts:

```
// 1
$(window).load(function () {
  $("video[autoplay]").get(0).play();
});


// 2
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
var video = $("video[autoplay]").get(0);

if (video.paused) {
  video.play();
}
});


// 3
$(window).on("touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel", function () {
  var video = $("video[autoplay]").get(0);

  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="" loop="" playsinline="" muted="">
  <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The first variant doesn't work at all.

The second one runs scripts inside of it, but the video doesn't play.

The third one runs scripts inside of it, but the video play only on the click!

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/pWwyoo).
Here is [website](http://silencer.website/tomatdesign-graphik/agency.html)

Comment: will be blocked ¿?

Comment: what browser are  you/they using? also seems like you forgot autoplay="autoplay"

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón what?

Comment: Autoplay will not work with mobile browsers because mobile will be on network data, and if any auto play video starts playing, then it will consume data without user's permission and knowledge. So this is disabled for mobile browsers by default.

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen I use Chrome 60 on the phone with Android 4.2.2

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay okay, but why does it start playing on click but not if I scroll or just touch when I use the third script?

Comment: Mobile browsers controls the script in the way that it won't trigger the event. `Click` is the actual event which tells browser that the user really wants to play it now.

Comment: just @HimanshuUpadhyay have said

Answer (score 2):

Autoplay will not work with mobile browsers because mobile will be on network data, and if any auto play video starts playing, then it will consume data without user's permission and knowledge. So this is disabled for mobile browsers by default.

But still you can check these url for your solution:

Since the release of iOS 10 Apple has allowed video autoplay: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Chrome 53 on Android also allowing video autoplay: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Comment: It is like was before, it works on the computer but doesn't work on the phones

Comment: ok, @SilencerWeb, sorry it didn't help you. Actually I am a web developer so can not help you more on mobile domain. I tried to guide you with my answer.